# Relationship Between Shift Operator and Backward Difference Operator (Finite Differences)

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

Consider $z_1,...,z_n$ and let $E(z_k) = z_{k+1}$ be a forward shift operator and let $\Delta_-(z_k) = z_k - z_{k-1}$ be a backward difference operator. I'm trying to show that $E = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\Delta_-^j$.

I'm just getting started with learning about finite difference operators, and this seems very unintuitive.

I understand so far that $\Delta_- = 1 - E^{-1}$. But this approach makes it seem as though the binomial series above will diverge in some sense. For reference, this is exercise 8.2 in Iserles 'A First Course in the Numerical Analysis of Differential Equations' second edition.

Comment: This is a formal ansatz. The convergence is not guaranteed. But if $z_k$ are generated through a very analytic function, this may be understood as extrapolation.  For the series approach, you can show $E^{-1} = I - \Delta_{-}$, but $\Delta_{-}$ is not a contraction map unless $z_k$ is restricted to the class that $\sup_{k}|z_k - z_{k-1}| < \alpha \sup_k |z_k|$ for some $\alpha < 1$. But this could be true if $z_k$ are generated by smooth function densely.

Comment: good question btw.